# AMD GPU drivers not installing Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, drivers, graphics, 20.04, amdgpu

I've been trying to be able to boot into Ubuntu 20.04 without having `nomodeset` in the grub (without it i get a black screen) and from what I can tell I have to install GPU drivers for my Radeon 5500xt graphics card, but every time I run amdgpu-install as follows:

```
sudo ./amdgpu-install -y
```

I get the following output at the end of run time

```
    ERROR: This package can only be installed on Ubuntu 18.04.
dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-pro-pin (--configure):
 installed amdgpu-pro-pin package post-installation script subprocess returned e
rror exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 amdgpu-pro-pin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libllvm9 libllvm9:i386 linux-headers-5.4.0-26 linux-headers-5.4.0-26-generic
  linux-image-5.4.0-26-generic linux-modules-5.4.0-26-generic
  linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-26-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  amdgpu-pro-pin*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 48.1 kB disk space will be freed.
(Reading database ... 259383 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing amdgpu-pro-pin (20.10-1048554) ...
(Reading database ... 259380 files and directories currently installed.)
Purging configuration files for amdgpu-pro-pin (20.10-1048554) ...
ERROR: Unable to install amdgpu-pro-pin.
This driver may not support the running operating system.
```

I hope there is someone that can help me with this problem
Thanks in advance

Comment: AFAIK AMD hasn't released any AMDGPU-PRO driver for ubuntu 20 just yet .

Comment: Oh so there are no GPU drivers for my GPU available on Ubuntu 20.04??

Comment: You can still use the builtin AMDGPU drivers if those work for you .And if not , I have no idea.

Comment: No the whole problem is I need to be able without nomodeset and installing the graphics drivers seems like the only option I have right now

Comment: @ParsaMousavi in my experience it struggles to show hq 1080 pixel movies. I have lots of lapses with RX580 on vanilla driver of Ubuntu 20.04 and Ryzen 7, so sadly going to downgrade just to watch moves.

Answer (score 3):

Do you see `ERROR: This package can only be installed on Ubuntu 18.04.`?

The package is incompatible with Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Yes I saw that but these are the GPU driver install files provided for Ubuntu on the AMD website for my GPU so I have no idea how to fix it

Comment: Does it say anything about Ubuntu releases they support? If these drivers were made for Ubuntu 18.04, it doesn't mean that they will work with 20.04.

Comment: I just checked and it does say that 20.04 is not supported

Comment: Thanks for the help I'll see what I can find with this information

Answer (score 2):

This is for Ubuntu 20.04:

[Radeon™ Software for Linux® 20.20 Release Notes](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-20-20)

Download links and installation instructions are available from the page.

Comment: New package doesn't work, just results in errors.

Comment: Try to use kernel 5.7 and above.